# Mapping a Map or List multiplies parent result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am having a problem with mapping a entity that contains a list (or map). I've tried various combinations of annotations but the two variations that work the 'best' both have this behavior. If the parent-object has, for example, 3 child objects, the parent object is retrieved three times.

### My Code

In my case i have an `UserOrder` object that contains pairs of `Product`s with a count. The datastructure looks like this

```java
@Entity
public class UserOrder{ 
    /* 
     * VARIATION 1 
     * I did actually vary some of these annotions, not all are necessary. 
     * I believe the @CollectionTable is the key here
     */
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable
    @Column
    @Embedded
    private List<ProductCount> products;

    /*
     * VARIATION 2
     */
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Map<Product, Integer> products = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();

    // get/set
    // ...
}

@Embeddable
/* Only used in variation 1 */
public class ProductCount{
    @OneToOne
    private Product product;

    @Column
    private Integer amount;

    // get/set
}

@Entity
public class Product
{
    // ...
}
```

Then this is called and displayed using something like this (this is for variation 2)

```html
<!-- Called via DAO/Service layers
List<Order> orders = getSession().createCriteria(UserOrder.class).list();
-->
<c:forEach items="${orders}" var="order">
    <fmt:formatDate value="${order.time}" type="both" />
    <c:forEach items="${order.products}" var="pc">
        ${pc.value} x ${pc.key.name}
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

For the record, I am using Spring (3.1), Hibernate (3.5) and I'd like to stay with JPA annotations.

### The Problem

When I retrieve the orders, I get a `UserOrder`-object for each of the products it contains, instead of one `UserOrder` for each order I have stored. So I get duplicates in my list, all with complete information of the products it contains. Orders without products are also included

- Order 1 -- Has 2 products

  - 1 x DogToy1
  - 3 x Cat Toy 1
- Order 1 -- Has 2 products

  - 1 x DogToy1
  - 3 x Cat Toy 1
- Order 2 -- Has 1 product

  - 3 x Cat Toy 1
- Order 3 -- Has 0 products

How do I make Hibernate return me one (1) `UserOrder` instead of one-for-each-product? Or, have I even taking the right approach to modelling this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

- lazy load the child collections (there should be an option to batch loading lazy loaded collections)
- use DistinctRootentityResulttransformer on the query

Comment: Lazy loading gives me trouble with closed sessions, but i also don't think its semantically correct since i'll usually need the contents of an order when I display one. I'll look into the Transformer but I'd rather not bring extra complexity into this

Comment: Ok, it's actually not hard to add the transformer. I'll add my implementation to your answer and accept it

Comment: have lazy loading does not mean it's always lazyloaded, you can specify fetch paths in queries to load associations for each use case differently

Comment: Comment by Joost: `// Create criteria
Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(UserOrder.class);
// Make sure we get only one root entity
c.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
// Return a list
return c.list();`